# What PrincipalContext does UserPrincipal.GetGroups() use if not specified?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, .net-4.6.2

In the case that I'm getting groups for a UserPrincipal identity (in an Active Directory role provider), and I use the UserPrincipal.GetGroups() function that does not require a PrincipalContext as parameter, what does it default to using for the PrincipalContext? I ask as in troubleshooting an issue, I'm seeing seeing it connect to a different AD server that is not the connected server for my PrincipalContext. Some code as an example:

```
using ( PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain, "domain", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate ) )
{
    UserPrincipal identity = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username );

    if (identity != null)
    {
        var groupList = identity.GetGroups();
    } 
}
```

If I output `context.ConnectedServer` I get a valid active server. However, `identity.GetGroups()` appears to connect to a different server (in my case, it's throwing a `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryServerDownException` because it's connecting to an old server). If I instead use `identity.GetGroups(context)`, the groups are correctly returned. Why does calling GetGroups without a PrincipalContext cause it to default to connecting to a different server?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem goes away if you use `identity.GetGroups(context)`?

Comment: As noted in my post, yes. I'm trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: Weird. I'd think it would use the `Context` property value from the `identity` object.

Comment: Weird, indeed. As a double check, I just output the `identity.Context.ConnectedServer` right before the `identity.GetGroups()` call, and it outputs the correct active server. But then the `GetGroups()` call fails trying to bind to an inactive server. This is happening in multiple environments - all trying to connect to the same inactive server.

Comment: It's kind of freaking me out that the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) doesn't seem to include the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.